# How to fix my createArrayFromCSVFile function?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

A long, long time ago I created or possible even 'borrowed' a bit of code I use to open CSV files and put the contents in arrays. It is now generating the following warning and creating a huge error.log file:

```
[29-Jul-2014 16:35:47] PHP Warning:  fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/muskie/domains/muschamp.ca/public_html/Muskie/muskLib.php on line 9
```

This is the function:

```
// Since I often had to do this, now I can do it in a single line of code
function createArrayFromCSVFile($fileName)
{
    $myArray = array();
    $file = fopen($fileName, 'r');

    while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
    {
        $myArray[] = $result;
    }

    fclose($file);

    return $myArray;
}
```

How best do I go about fixing this method so it does not generate the warning? The code itself runs, though Rotten Tomatoes seems to no longer let me use their API but that is another problem...

I have looked at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and an [alternate method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). The seem to be debating the best way to do this. Did the PHP on my web host change and I just need another argument for fgetscsv?

Comment: `fgetcsv` is only the function that _informs_ you about the error, it is not the one _causing_ it – that is `fopen`, which fails and therefor returns `false`. So how to prevent that from failing resp. checking if it did so is what you actually want to research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error means is that, the CSV file you're using in your `fopen()` function does not exist or is invalid.
When you try and open an invalid/non-existent file, `fopen();` returns false.

See: [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

To Simplify your function you could do the following.

```
function createArrayFromCSVFile($fileName)
{
    if(!file_exists($fileName)){
        return false;
        //or you could return an empty array
        //return array();
    }
    $myArray = array_map('str_getcsv', file($fileName));

    return $myArray;
}
```

But I would reccomend adding some error checking/validation ect. Like `file_exists()` or w/e.

**EDIT:**

 Added some validation.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda developed that hypothesis. Unfortunantly there are other problems related to bad or unexpected data from APIs, but that error flooded my log so I need to squash it.